# What are WooCommerce starter themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce, theme-recommendation

I've done created a lot of Wordpress themes and plugins, but I haven't done much with the Wordpress WooCommerce plugin from WooThemes.

If someone asked me what general theme they should work with to learn about themes, I would suggest one of Wordpress' defaults, like `TwentyFourteen`

However, for someone who is creating an online store with Worpdress / WooCommerce I would not know where to tell them to start.

1. What themes are available as a starting point for working with WooCommerce?
2. What other resources are available for getting started?

Comment: After doing a lot of research [I ended up using Shopify instead](http://shopify.com/?friend=scarheal). While it has a monthly fee I don't have to worry about paying for web hosting, thwarting hackers, or paying for yearly licenses for WooCommerce upgrades.

Comment: The underscores starter theme now has support for WooCommerce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you are going for a e-commerce website here are some really good themes, plugins, and trickes that you will find really helpfull

### Themes

> **Sommerce Shop**: http://themeforest.net/item/sommerce-shop-a-versatile-ecommerce-theme/542001
>
> **Demo**: http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=sommerce
>
> wordpress theme

---

> **Mojo Theme:** http://splashingpixels.com/themes/mojo/
>
> **Demo:** http://mojo.splashingpixels.com/
>
> wordpress theme

---

> **Eggo Theme:** http://splashingpixels.com/themes/eggo/
>
> **Demo:** http://eggo.splashingpixels.com/
>
> wordpress theme

---

> **Storefront:** Designer http://storefrontthemes.com/themes/designer/
>
> wordpress theme

---

> **Wootique:** http://www.woothemes.com/products/wootique/
>
> **Demo:** http://demo2.woothemes.com/wootique/
>
> wordpress theme

---

> **Inspire WooCommerce:** http://www.woothemes.com/products/inspire/
>
> **Demo:** http://demo.woothemes.com/inspire/
>
> wordpress theme

---

more themes @

http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress/ecommerce

and

[WooCommerce Themes](http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/?prod_cat%5B%5D=1050&s=&post_type=product)

---

### Plugins

> **WP e-Commerce Plugin**
>
> http://getshopped.org/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/

---

> **woocommerce**
>
> http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

---

> **jigoshop**
>
> http://www.jigoshop.com/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/jigoshop/
>
> http://try.jigoshop.com/

---

> **Cart66**
>
> http://cart66.com/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/cart66-lite/

---

> **Zingiri Web Shop**
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/zingiri-web-shop/

---

> **Shopp**
>
> https://shopplugin.net/

---

> **Ecwid**
>
> http://www.ecwid.com/key-features.html

---

> **Usability Dynamics**
>
> http://usabilitydynamics.com/

---

> **Marketpress shopping cart**
>
> http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/marketpress-shopping-cart

---

> **WordPress Simple Paypal Shopping Cart**
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/

---

> **eShop**
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/eshop/

---

> **wpStoreCart**
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpstorecart/

---

> **shopify** (non wordpress but integrable)
>
> http://www.shopify.com/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/shopify/

---

> **magento**(non wordpress but integrable)
>
> http://www.magentocommerce.com/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/

---

> **oscommerce**(non wordpress but integrable)
>
> http://www.oscommerce.com/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/oscommerce/
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-online-store/

### Trickes

You can interagate many other commerce system in to your wordpress like FoxyCart in smiler way as Chris Coyier from from css-tricks tough here

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/45-using-foxycart-for-ecommerce/

Another ttrick

http://www.wordpress-ecommerce.com/wordpress-shop-using-nextgen-gallery-and-wp-shopping-cart-7

Another trick

http://www.wordpress-ecommerce.com/how-to-turn-your-wordpress-site-into-a-digital-photo-store-and-sell-photos-securely-654

Comment: http://jigoshop.com/ is also a good one I think.

Comment: @sisir oh yes it also a really good i am including it in to my list if you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is worth looking at [Jigoshop themes](http://jigoshop.com/extend/themes/). Next there are [WooCommerce themes](http://www.woothemes.com/themes/woocommerce-themes/) based on [WooCommerce plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) which is quiet derived from Jigoshop plugin (I would give a try to [Sommerce Shop theme](http://themeforest.net/item/sommerce-shop-a-versatile-ecommerce-theme/542001) too).

All in all my favorite plugin is still WP e-Commerce plugin and its [system of templates](http://getshopped.org/extend/themes/). I used one great theme with lot of functionality based on this plugin not long time ago - [WP FlexiShop](http://themeforest.net/item/wp-flexishop-a-versatile-wp-ecommerce-theme/137144). You can also see some magic in [eStore theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/estore/) from ElegantThemes. Additionally very good looking theme [Balita](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/19/free-e-commerce-wordpress-theme-balita/) is offered for free. (there is lot of else like [Mazine Wordpress Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/mazine-wordpress-theme-a-wp-ecommerce-theme/198602))

New rising star on the field of WP commerce solutions is [Cart66](http://cart66.com/) (also offered in [lite free version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cart66-lite/)) and its [themes](http://cart66.com/integration/themes-for-cart66/). From my point of view this plugin has its ups and you should have a look at it as well.

Something else [Viroshop](http://themeforest.net/item/viroshop-professional-ecommerce-theme/101867)...

Comment: +1. Thank you for a well written and comprehensive response. I'll be upvoting everyone with a useful post.

Answer (score 1):

Just reread your question before posting the following, so my answer's kinda not what you're asking but I would say if you're just starting with WordPress ecommerce, save yourself some wp-ecommerce headache and check out jigoshop.

I've worked with Jigoshop, Marketpress & WP Ecommerce and would say Jigoshop is by far the best of the three. The Jigoshop plugin is built to work with twentyten/twentyeleven so you could stick with either of those as a base / parent theme. They also have their own premium themes which, while reasonably expensive for themes are probably a good place to start to see how they've coded them.

Comment: Great! I've given you an upvote. I am looking for advice here if so if someone recommends Jigoshop that's fine. I'd like to see what all people come back with and I plan to upvote anything helpful and award the bounty to the most helpful (and/or comprehensive post). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ive used Thematic with wp e-commerce, it integrated pretty well overall with WP e-commerce, in fact i think at some level both developers work together.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use tokokoo.com, my former employee. This company have legion of coder who  expert on wp-eCommerce plugin.

on Or you can use theme from colorlabsprojects.com, they don't have many of eCommerce theme. But i think their design is quite exceptional.

Fyi, it's not a promotion. I dont work on both of company

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the woo themes E-Commerce theme framework. Woo Themes framework is fine coded and it is user friendly optimized. Majorly they have premium themes but they also have some free E-Commerce theme. Woo would be an all in one package.

[WooCommerce Themes by WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/?prod_cat%5B%5D=1050&s=&post_type=product)