# How to sell an album for download

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, genesis-theme-framework

I'm trying to deliver a set of nine audio files, as part of a single purchase for download.  My first thought was to make an RSS file as the actual purchased item and then the customer would be able to download the nine actual files using iTunes from that feed.  I'm not convinced that this is the best approach.

I have tried to deliver an RSS file but the file simply arrives as an XML document in the download folder of the users browser.  I believe I would need to use  itpc:// in the URL, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to try and see a collection of recordings, not unlike selling an album.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to use a service like [Fetch](http://fetchapp.com) or [Quickly](http://quixly.com). Although these aren't integrated into WordPress proper, they're the best way I've found for selling digital assets on the web.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is an eCommerce plugin for wordpress like [WP e-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) with some extension that gives [buy and download](http://getshopped.org/premium-upgrades/premium-plugin/download-manager/) features or [Cart66](http://cart66.com/) or [Cart66 lite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cart66-lite/). If you want a detailed list on wordpress eCommerce plugins and themes check out [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35063/what-wordpress-e-commerce-theme-should-i-use-to-get-started/35786#35786) answer of mine. Do check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35063/what-wordpress-e-commerce-theme-should-i-use-to-get-started/35786#35786) , it will help you so you do not choose a costly one as there are many free ones out there as well.